# AWS analytics for iOS app crash in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, afnetworking, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated AWS analytics(2.1.1), Facebook SDK(4.1.0) and AFNetworking(2.5.4) in one application. but app is crashing while launching itself. here is the screen shot for crash. any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have just done some inspecting in AFNetworking code.

When AFNetworking is loading, more specifically its class [AFURLSessionManager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m), they do some method swizzling on `NSURLSessionTask` replacing the original methods with their own implementations. The reason being

> A workaround for issues related to key-value observing the `state` of an `NSURLSessionTask`

This is a dirty hack in `AFNetworking` and IMHO they should never have done something like that because it breaks the Apple API in an unexpected way. Probably your only way to fix this is either remove `AFNetworking` and write the communication layer by yourself (which is pretty easy) or include the AFNetworking code directly (not using a pod) and remove the swizzling part.

I am not absolutely sure why the crash is happening but it is probably a use case not expected by AFNetworking developers. I would advise to put a breakpoint to `af_resume` and use the debugger to get information about `self` (e.g. `po self`, `po [self class]` etc.) and raise an issue with AFNetworking on github.

Comment: Thank you @Sulthan for valuable suggestion, i will check this.

Comment: @naresh I can't currently find the exact problem in AWS that is not compatible with the swizzling so I cannot advice for a simpler solution. AFNetworking probably forgot about a specific use case that AWS is using.

Comment: Okey @Sultan, i am using AWS for analytics just followed the document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/analytics.html

Comment: @naresh There is no problem with AWS. It's AFNetworking that is breaking the API, making AWS crash.

Comment: Okey, any simple fix for this, because i need AFNetworking for downloading and caching images,

Comment: actually i commented line number 357 in screen shot its working fine, but does it cause any other issue? @Sultan

Comment: po self giving AFURLSessionTaskSwizzling

Comment: there is not issue with AFNetworking 2.4.0, used pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git', :tag => '2.4.0'. let me log a bug in AFNetworking git.